# Biggest change in size from birth

Tags: mammals, growth

Which mammal has the largest change in size from birth to fully grown percentage wise?

Comment: I  guess it maybe a marsupial for example red kangaroo.

Comment: If the answer below [addressed your problem](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**@JM97** is correct.

According to **[National Geographic](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/2015/08/150828-baby-mammal-size-differences-panda-kangaroo-science/)** >>

The gestation period of a **Red Kangaroo** is 33 days and it's baby at birth weighs a mere **0.03 oz**. To put it into a more precise perspective, on birth, the baby weighs **1/100,000** of an adult red kangaroo's weight.

Second place goes to the baby of a **Giant Panda**; at birth it weighs 3.2oz which is **1/900** of an adult giant panda's weight.

Comment: How about platypus?

Comment: Although [platyplus babies are almost the size of a jellybean](https://www.google.ca/amp/www.answers.com/amp/Q/What_size_is_a_baby_platypus?client=ms-android-samsung), their baby to adult ratio isnt much. Because adult platypus usually extend upto 15 inches.